# Rails 3 Jquery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to implement a simple dialog with Jquery and Rails 3. I installed Jquery via the gem and the 'rails generate jquery:install --ui' command. Everything seems to work fine. I can submit forms via Ajax and render unobtrusive JS with js.erb files. My problem is I can't get a simple freakin dialog to work.

Here's my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog();
});
```

and the html:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog">BLAH BLAH BLAH</div>
```

Simple enough right?? Well when the page loads I get this from Firebug:

```
$("#dialog").dialog is not a function
```

I can see both the js min and the normal js files included. I can even navigate to the dialog function in jquery-ui.js so I don't know why this isn't working. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, note that you can control the load order in config/application.rb:

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery jquery-ui.min rails)
```

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you must have a typo somewhere. You seem to have everything else in place.

Seeing as I had not used the jquery gem I just created a project with it, created a project, a empty model, "page", and added your code to the application.html.erb file , replacing the  yield, and everything worked .

My application.html.erb

```
  1 <!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                
  2 <html>
  3 <head>
  4   <title>Jq</title>
  5   <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  6   <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  7   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
  8   <script>
  9   $(document).ready(function(){
 10     //console.log("loaded");
 11     $("#dialog").dialog();
 12   });
 13 
 14 </script>
 15 
 16 </head>
 17 
 18 <body>
 19 
 20 
 21 
 22 
 23 <div id="dialog" title="Dialog">BLAH BLAH BLAH</div>
 24 
 25 
 26 </body>
 27 </html>
```

You do need to add the CSS of course..

Comment: I rebuilt a brand new app from scratch just to make sure nothing else was interfering. I created the same thing as above. I still get the error! I put up a dev version of my full app here: http://dev.high-elevation.com Anyone have any thoughts??

Answer (score -1):

Fixed! After hours on the Googler and not finding anything. I started playing with the default Jquery files downloaded directly from the main site. Interchanging these with the generated UJS files I realized the order makes a difference. So renaming the jquery-ui.js file to jqueryui.js insured that the jquery.js files are loaded before the UI files. I guess this is obvious but I haven't seen much on the Jquery file order and using the generator to install Jquery names them that way. I'm using a Mac, sooo maybe finder ordered the files differently then other machines???? I know I can't be the only person who's had this issue when using default names. Nonetheless whenever using Jquery always load UI after the main Jquery library!!